# How to pass data within views when programmatically creating a button to go to the next view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a button programatically within ViewController. When the user taps on this button, it goes to a new view controller named SecondViewController. Using segues in the storyboard, I know how to pass data between view controllers and have done it in the past.

My question: if I’m not using the storyboard and am doing this programatically, how do I do this?

SecondViewController has an NSString property named data.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    [self.view addSubview:button];

}

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    //load the street view container
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"firstToSecond"]) {

        //send coordinates to container
        SecondViewController *embed = segue.destinationViewController;
        embed.data = @"test";

    }

}

- (void)aMethod:(UIButton*)button
{
    NSLog(@"Button  clicked.");

    UIViewController *myController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: myController animated:YES];

    //I get an error on these 2 lines of code within Xcode.
    MyCustomSegue *segue = [[MyCustomSegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"firstToSecond" source:self destination:SecondViewController];
    [self prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender];
    [segue perform];

}
```

In xcode, I get an error on these 2 lines:

```
    MyCustomSegue *segue = [[MyCustomSegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"firstToSecond" source:self destination:SecondViewController];
    [self prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender];
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you create your segue in StoryBoard ? Just ctrl-drag from the viewController icon (yellow icon on bottom of viewController) of the source VC, to somewhere in the destination viewController. give this segue an identifier (i.e. segueToVC2)

and now call this segue programmatically in your aMethod:

```
- (void)aMethod:(UIButton*)button
{
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToVC2" sender:button];
}
```

> as we define the segue id to segueToVC2, we need to use this also in prepareForSegue

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    //load the street view container
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueToVC2"]) {
        //send coordinates to container
        SecondViewController *embed = segue.destinationViewController;
        embed.data = @"test";
    }
}
```

Comment: When the button is clicked and this segue gets performed, how would I pass data to SecondViewController?

Comment: As usually, in your **prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender**

Answer (score 3):

if you want to add a viewController to the hierarchie using `[self.navigationController pushViewController:myController animated:YES]` you don't need to create a segue programmatically.

`prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` is called just before destinationViewController ist pushed to give you the chance to modify or pass data to it before it appears on the screen. so don't call this function manually. all you need to do is move your code from there to between

```
UIViewController *myController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
myController.data = @"test";
[self.navigationController pushViewController: myController animated:YES];
```

Comment: So in the example you gave, how would I pass data to SecondViewController from the current view controller?

Comment: another good option would be subclassing UIviewController an instantiate it like this:  CustomViewController *second = [[CustomViewController alloc] initWithData: @"test"]